# Connect to MS SQL Server 2005 using Win 11 and MSOLEDBSQL19

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ado, windows-11

Ive been having some trouble establishing a connection to an old MS SQL Server 2005 (which is used for some internal tooling) from Windows 11 using ADO and **MSOLEDBSQL19**.

Connecting to the server from Win 10 using the same driver works fine. Connecting from Win 11 does not.

I have read that this old SQL Server version uses TLS 1.0 or 1.1, both of which are disabled on Windows 11 by default. I have reactivated them using IISCrypto but still no luck. I can however connect to the Server via the SQL Management Studio. Using the SQL Native Client driver and **even MSOLEDBSQL version 18 also works fine**.

Therefore, the issue must be MSOLEDBSQL19 (or my usage of it) but I couldn't find much info about which changes between driver versions caused this. In my connection string I think I should have anything disabled that would cause issues. I played with it for a while but couldnt get a cs that worked. Here are two of the ones I tried.

```
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;Data Source=<host>;Initial Catalog=<db>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
TrustServerCertificate=Yes;Encrypt=Optional;Use Encryption for Data=Optional
```

```
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;Data Source=<host>;Initial Catalog=<db>;Encrypt=No;Use Encryption for Data=No
```

The error this gives me is just a generic error message saying that the connection was closed by the remote.
[image: vbs script with error message]

I know that these requirements are quite silly (MSOLEDBSQL19 + SQL Server 2005) but I hope this isnt impossible as it worked on Windows 10.
Theres probably something very obvious im missing here so Id be very grateful for some advice.

Comment: There's no such thing as SQL Server 2003. What version do you actually have? Also: you should know SQL Server 2012 and earlier are **end of life** and haven't seen any updates in several years... _not even critical security patches_. Updating those systems to a supported platform (that gets security patches) is job #1 here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hi there! Sorry yes I totally mixed that one up, the server is an SQL Server 2005. I agree that the server should be migrated to something newer but sadly thats a process that will take a while and we need a way to access the data now.

Comment: Fine... but just remember: this is **important**. It's **NOT** something to put off, especially if the version typo means you're also running Windows Server 2003.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also the error isn't in English, which isn't helpful; all content on [so] should be in English.

Comment: From the [ADO Support Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/support-policies-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#ado-support-policies) of the OLEDB provider version matrix: `ADO applications can use the SQLOLEDB OLE DB provider that is included with Windows if they don't require any of the features of SQL Server 2005 (9.x) or later.` Maybe that will work.

Answer (score 2):

If the "2003" typo means you're also running Windows Server 2003, you have a problem. SQL Server's encryption support also depends on the underlying OS, and Windows Server 2003 forces you back all the way to TLS 1.0, which is so broken now you may just as well turn encryption off completely. Also remember when you enable the older protocols you have to reboot your computer before the change takes effect.

Comment: Right, totally makes sense. Is there a way to get data off it using the new driver though? The server is only available in a small private network so using TLS1.0, while not good, may not be fatal. I have rebooted my computer and other drivers work fine, only MSOLEDBSQL19 doesnt work.

Comment: @RedCube yes, restore the backups in a SQL Server 2019 machine. Seriously. No matter how big these are, they're probably so small they can run on a laptop and still provide higher performance and reliability.

Comment: To build on the "restore the backups idea"... a refurbished desktop from 2018 with a new SSD costs less than $200 and will grossly outperform even top-tier hardware available from the 2003 era. Add a small business Windows Server Essentials license for about $500 (maybe less if you want to count CALs), and if the database size is less than 10 GB the new version of SQL Server is free... so you can get back to a supported state for about $700.